# CEFpython browser loads blank white page on windows, but works perfectly on mac

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, cefpython

I edited the code from CEFpython's github page, the one that uses wxPython.  It works fine on my mac but when the browser launches on windows it only loads a blank white screen.

I'm trying out both wxPython and CEFpython for the first time.
I am trying to use wxPython as a wrapper for the cef browser, using django as the server in the background. 
 I followed the tutorial on CEFpython's Github page https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py
I edited it and it works on mac but when I tried to run it on windows all I get is a blank white page with a small square top left.
What I've tried:
1) I tried loading google.com instead of 127.0.0.1:8000.
2) I guessed that it might have been that the server had not started before the frame containing the browser, I used a thread to delay for about 15 seconds and called Reload on the browser
3) It works perfectly on Mac so I edited the code and leaving only the windows related code, the same thing. 
Please Help!
Sorry if I pasted all the code, I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you in advance.

browser.py

```py
import wx
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import sys
import platform
import os

# Platforms
WINDOWS = (platform.system() == "Windows")
LINUX = (platform.system() == "Linux")
MAC = (platform.system() == "Darwin")

if MAC:
    try:
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        from AppKit import NSApp
    except ImportError:
        print("[wxpython.py] Error: PyObjC package is missing, "
              "cannot fix Issue #371")
        print("[wxpython.py] To install PyObjC type: "
              "pip install -U pyobjc")
        sys.exit(1)


def check_versions():
    print("[wxpython.py] CEF Python {ver}".format(ver=cef.__version__))
    print("[wxpython.py] Python {ver} {arch}".format(
            ver=platform.python_version(), arch=platform.architecture()[0]))
    print("[wxpython.py] wxPython {ver}".format(ver=wx.version()))
    # CEF Python version requirement
    assert cef.__version__ >= "66.0", "CEF Python v66.0+ required to run this"


def scale_window_size_for_high_dpi(width, height):
    """Scale window size for high DPI devices. This func can be
    called on all operating systems, but scales only for Windows.
    If scaled value is bigger than the work area on the display
    then it will be reduced."""
    if not WINDOWS:
        return width, height
    (_, _, max_width, max_height) = wx.GetClientDisplayRect().Get()
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    (width, height) = cef.DpiAware.Scale((width, height))
    if width > max_width:
        width = max_width
    if height > max_height:
        height = max_height
    return width, height


class BrowserFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = None
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="NETS Framework")
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)
        # Set wx.WANTS_CHARS style for the keyboard to work.
        # This style also needs to be set for all parent controls.
        self.browser_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        self.browser_panel.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnSetFocus)
        self.browser_panel.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        check_versions()
        sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
        settings = {}
        settings["context_menu"] = {'enabled':False}
        if MAC:
            # Issue #442 requires enabling message pump on Mac
            # and calling message loop work in a timer both at
            # the same time. This is an incorrect approach
            # and only a temporary fix.
            settings["external_message_pump"] = True

        if WINDOWS:
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences, PyArgumentList
            cef.DpiAware.EnableHighDpiSupport()
        cef.Initialize(settings=settings)
        if MAC:
            # Make the content view for the window have a layer.
            # This will make all sub-views have layers. This is
            # necessary to ensure correct layer ordering of all
            # child views and their layers. This fixes Window
            # glitchiness during initial loading on Mac (Issue #371).
            NSApp.windows()[0].contentView().setWantsLayer_(True)

        if LINUX:
            # On Linux must show before embedding browser, so that handle
            # is available (Issue #347).
            self.Show()
            # In wxPython 3.0 and wxPython 4.0 on Linux handle is
            # still not yet available, so must delay embedding browser
            # (Issue #349).
            if wx.version().startswith("3.") or wx.version().startswith("4."):
                wx.CallLater(100, self.embed_browser)
            else:
                # This works fine in wxPython 2.8 on Linux
                self.embed_browser()
        else:
            self.embed_browser()
            self.Show()

    def embed_browser(self):
        window_info = cef.WindowInfo()
        (width, height) = self.browser_panel.GetClientSize().Get()
        assert self.browser_panel.GetHandle()
        window_info.SetAsChild(self.browser_panel.GetHandle(),
                               [0, 0, width, height])
        self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(window_info,
                                             url="http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        self.browser.SetClientHandler(FocusHandler())

    def OnSetFocus(self, _):
        if not self.browser:
            return
        if WINDOWS:
            cef.WindowUtils.OnSetFocus(self.browser_panel.GetHandle(),
                                       0, 0, 0)
        self.browser.SetFocus(True)

    def OnSize(self, _):
        if not self.browser:
            return
        if WINDOWS:
            cef.WindowUtils.OnSize(self.browser_panel.GetHandle(),
                                   0, 0, 0)
        elif LINUX:
            (x, y) = (0, 0)
            (width, height) = self.browser_panel.GetSize().Get()
            self.browser.SetBounds(x, y, width, height)
        self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        print("[wxpython.py] OnClose called")
        if not self.browser:
            # May already be closing, may be called multiple times on Mac
            return

        if not MAC:
            # On Mac shutdown is called in OnClose
            cef.Shutdown()

        if MAC:
            # On Mac things work differently, other steps are required
            self.browser.CloseBrowser()
            self.clear_browser_references()
            self.Destroy()
            global g_count_windows
            g_count_windows -= 1
            if g_count_windows == 0:
                cef.Shutdown()
                wx.GetApp().ExitMainLoop()
                # Call _exit otherwise app exits with code 255 (Issue #162).
                # noinspection PyProtectedMember
                os._exit(0)
        else:
            # Calling browser.CloseBrowser() and/or self.Destroy()
            # in OnClose may cause app crash on some paltforms in
            # some use cases, details in Issue #107.
            self.browser.ParentWindowWillClose()
            event.Skip()
            self.clear_browser_references()

    def clear_browser_references(self):
        # Clear browser references that you keep anywhere in your
        # code. All references must be cleared for CEF to shutdown cleanly.
        self.browser = None


class FocusHandler(object):
    def OnGotFocus(self, browser, **_):
        # Temporary fix for focus issues on Linux (Issue #284).
        if LINUX:
            print("[wxpython.py] FocusHandler.OnGotFocus:"
                  " keyboard focus fix (Issue #284)")
            browser.SetFocus(True)
```

main.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import time
from icecream import ic

from threading import Thread
from source.Nets.wxBrowser import BrowserFrame
from source.Nets.server import start_server_subprocess


# This puts the server in a subprocess, don't forget to close it
class ServerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        ic("Starting Server")
        start_server_subprocess()


class StartPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        # create the text display to basic info
        self.app_info = wx.StaticText(self, label="Enter the IP Address of Mother Server"
                                                  " \n If you want to use the practice mode simply click"
                                                  " practice mode button and carry on with the program")
        # create the text entry box to enter the ip
        self.ip_address = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="http://127.0.0.1:8000", )
        # create two buttons to either select client mode or practice mode
        self.client_button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Client Mode", )
        self.practice_button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Practice Mode", )
        # Add the buttons to a Horizontal sizer
        # This allows the client and practice buttons to stack side by side
        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.client_button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer2.Add(self.practice_button, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        # Add the app_info and ip_text to a vertical sizer to allow them
        # stack on each other add the sizer2 to the button
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.app_info, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.ip_address, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.sizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        # Create button Bind actions
        self.practice_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPractice)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClient, self.client_button)

    def onClient(self, event):
        # load the new frame using max screen and browser to the
        # IP provided, use thread to wait, and use error handling
        # to fail gracefully
        print("Hit client")

    def onPractice(self, event):
        # Use a thread to start the local django server
        # Verify that the server has started
        # TODO At some point implement a method to check for an updated sqlite server that has more questions
        # Switch to the browser frame and local server
        self.practice_button.Disable()
        self.client_button.Disable()
        ic("Attempting to start server")
        ServerThread()
        self.practice_button.SetLabelText("Loading Process, Please wait")
        self.app_info.SetLabel("You will be logged into the practice mode. Enjoy!")
        time.sleep(3)
        # TODO Implement button
        # This allows the whole pre-existing panel to be destroyed and we implement a button that can allow the app
        # To gracefully close all frames including cef and django sub-process
        #self.Destroy()
        #self.close_all_button = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit NETS")
        browser_frame = BrowserFrame()






class StartFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        # The style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX) command helps to fix the size of
        # the page to make it non resizable and of fixed width and height.
        # This can also be achived using
        # self.SetMaxSize(wx.Size(400, 300))
        # self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(400, 300))
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title,
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX), size=(400, 300))

        start_panel = StartPanel(self)
        # Create status bar
        self.status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.status_bar.SetStatusText("NETS: Active")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = StartFrame(None, "Nets").Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

server.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import django
from django.core.management import call_command
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# TODO Clean up and select which process to use to start django
# TODO Note, any method you implement must be able to give some form of log
# TODO FOR debugging ease,  You must ensure that you kill the server process
# TODO ON exit from the app itself


def start_server_subprocess():
    process = Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'runserver'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    process.wait()
    return process


# This method starts the server in the same thread as the main app
# This leads to freezing, the subprocess method has been chosen
# This is kept for learning purposes!!!
def start_server():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Nets.settings')
    django.setup()
    try:
        call_command("runserver", noreload=True)
    except Exception as e:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
        print(message)
```

Comment: Does the original wxpython.py example work fine? What if you reload page using mouse context menu?

Comment: Yes, the original works fine. I think it's something I'm doing wrong. Reload page using mouse context menu? I went to my code and renabled context menu but I cant right click. It works fine on mac but on windows all i get is https://imgur.com/a/t4W8k8m

Comment: It looks like the browser window is not resized at all. Check if `OnSize` method is called.

Comment: The calls to `cef.Initialize` and `cef.DpiAware.EnableHighDpiSupport` should be done before wx app is initialized. Take a look at the originl wxpython.py example. In yours case you're initializing it too late.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/85A2gpNj This works. I'll check to see if The calls to cef.Initialize and cef.DpiAware.EnableHighDpiSupport fix the old code

Comment: I used the original wxpython.py example to create the new code pastebin.com/85A2gpNj  and but the old code even after adding cef.Initialize and cef.DpiAware.EnableHighDpiSupport before calling wx.app does not work. I think I did not correctly implement the wxpython.py example when I was creating my own script. It works now so i'm happy. Thank you for your help.